# Webpack Angular2 Typescript: EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

I try to use webpack for a module development: i use npm link command to get my custom module in my sample application.

But i have this error: 
[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLHub.png)

If i put my component (.ts, .html) in the app source, no error, it works.
So where is the mistake?

EDIT: I have this error for all my components

spinner.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'an-spinner',
 styles: [
    `
    ... DELETE to limit the number of line codes
    `,
 ],
 template: require( './spinner.component.html'),
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy {
 private currentTimeout: number = undefined;
 private isDelayedRunning: boolean = false;

 @Input()
 public delay: number = 300;

 @Input()
 public set visible(value) {
     if (! value) {
        this.cancelTimeout();
        this.isDelayedRunning = false;
     } else if (! this.currentTimeout) {
        this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isDelayedRunning = value;
            this.cancelTimeout(); }, this.delay);
     }
 }

 private cancelTimeout(): void {
     clearTimeout(this.currentTimeout);
     this.currentTimeout = undefined;
 }

 ngOnDestroy(): any {
     this.cancelTimeout();
 }
}
```

spinner.component.html:

```
<div [hidden]="!isDelayedRunning" class="containerspin">
<div  class="spinner">
    <div class="sk-fading-circle">
        <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
        <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: The error message is about `SpinnerComponent` your code shows `TestSpinnerComponent`. Please add images (screenshot) direct to the question instead of linking to external resources. External resources are prone to become unavailable and can make this question useless for future visitors.

Comment: Have you checked other questions? The error message sounds quite familiar.

Comment: Yes i checked other questions. But any solution solve my problems.

Comment: I modify te source code: TestSpinnerComponent (component test in my application source) to SpinnerComponent (component in my own module)

Comment: I think this is more a problem with webpack or so on the module configuration that I develop